# php WhatsApp API: Identity error while trying to log in

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am using PHP [WhatsApp Library](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/). As per instructions I got my login and password. Upon using I am getting error:

```
] Logging in as 'SmartConnect Agent' (12334) tx  <stream:features></stream:features>

tx  <auth user="12334" mechanism="WAUTH-2"></auth>

rx  <from s.whatsapp.net=""></from>

rx  <stream:features></stream:features>

rx  <challenge>fafa1216bdf3c4c4528e10d80b29c6026493682d</challenge>

tx  <response>19d8120136e5897f38fe0904e54611cd8510f029bdd97f077f460faba15bc68cd0644e87ebf4b8288a143dc1914cb61bf4bfa2f17e0d7187afa8fcd18e69bb2b75d4f2da549c3d3c3facedd808bc</response>

rx  <failure>
rx    <not-authorized></not-authorized>
rx  </failure>
```

Upon running *blockchecker.php* I get. Even same thing when I am retying to register by using **registerTool.php**

```
Wrong identity. 
Array
(
    [cc] => 92
    [in] => 1234566
    [lg] => en
    [lc] => PK
    [id] => >zv?+?????w!l?v?5b?
    [mistyped] => 6
    [network_radio_type] => 1
    [simnum] => 1
    [s] => 
    [copiedrc] => 1
    [hasinrc] => 1
    [rcmatch] => 1
    [pid] => 579
    [extexist] => 1
    [extstate] => 1
)
stdClass Object
(
    [status] => fail
    [reason] => incorrect
    [sms_length] => 6
    [voice_length] => 6
    [sms_wait] => 0
    [voice_wait] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It generated multiple IDentity file of a same number. I removed all and it generated new password.